# df.loc using index in slicer return nan

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate over a dateFrame and get the max of column between certain rows, the problem is when I am putting the index value over a number I get nan:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index >= 51:
            print(df.loc[index:(index - 51), 'close'].max())
```

for this, I get a nan value.
but if I use numbers in the slicer like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index >= 51:
            print(df.loc[0:51, 'close'].max())
```

I will get the result not the one I need because I need it to be a moving window but this is just to show the problem.

any ideas why it won't accept the index as a valid slicer?

Comment: Please can you post sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you have the `loc` index slice backwards, causing nothing to be returned; on the first iteration, your slice is `df.loc[51:0, 'close'].max()`.  Instead:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index >= 51:
        print(df.loc[index-51:index,'close'].max())

#first iteration: df.loc[0:51,'close']
```

I'm assuming your index are integers/numbers, hence why you can mix integers and column names using `loc`?  Otherwise I think `iloc` could work.

---

Amendment: this is what I was thinking by using `iloc`, but it is (in my eyes) no different than your method:

```
close_iloc = df.columns.get_loc('close') #gets the integer number needed for iloc to reference 'close'
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if i >= 51:
        print(df.iloc[i-51:i,close_iloc].max())
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but for iloc I need a specific value, while I am trying to calculate based on the previous row which I don't know the exact value.

Comment: I think either way you will be iterating over each row one by one; `iterrows` produces the row name while doing a different iteration would give the index numbers, which may be useful if you had an index that was non-numeric (so you could still subtract).  I'll post what I was thinking in my answer